# React Functional Custom Button Not Registering A Click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So here is my functional Button component

```
export const MyButton = (props) => {
    return (
        <button className="myButton">{props.text}</button>
    )
}
```

And I used it in another page like

```
<MyButton text="Update" onClick={this.checkIt} />
```

Where that checkIt function is just console logging the state of the class I used it in. But for some reason, it isn't registering the click at all. How can I go about solving it? I implemented in a similar way for input field where I used the `props.onChange(event.target.value)` and that is working properly.

Comment: Finally, your dom element should receive a handle. In your case, you should assign a handle to <button />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use onClick on MyButton component directly because MyButton component isn't a Native DOM element it is just another REACT component and onClick is treated as another property MyButton Component. What you need to do is, inside of MyButton component pass the onClick component to DOM element Button

```
export const MyButton = (props) => {
  return (
    <button className="myButton" onClick={props.onClick}>{props.text}</button>
   )
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should attach events in child components, otherwise it's not bind to actual UI at all!

Solution 1:

```
export const MyButton = ({text, ...others}) => {
    return (
        <button className="myButton" {...others}>{text}</button>
    )
}
```

Solution 2:

```
export const MyButton = ({text, onClick}) => {
    return (
        <button className="myButton" onClick={onClick}>{text}</button>
    )
}
```